# Why does my background music stop when the player object gets destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I work with Unity 5.5.4 and I'm still learning.

My problem is when the `player(object)` gets `destroyed(destroy(gameobject))`, my backgroud music stops playing, even if I place my music in `Arenamanager(gameobject)`, not in `player(gameobject)`.

I don't have a function like `audio.stop` or something like that in my script and I already untagged the `player(gameobject)` and I still can't solve it.

Here is my death function:

```
Void Death() { 
    Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Destroy(this.gameobject);
}
```

Comment: Stop editing the question, you're making it worse every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your player is most likely holding the AudioListener.

So when you destroy, there is nothing left to listen to your music.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats solve it, i put the audio listener on the camera that follow my player, another question pls, where is the better place to put it? Gamemanajer or arenamanaer?

Comment: Attach to empty GameObject that cannot be destroyed

Comment: Thankyou, vry much, bless u, hehe